# Incorrect Zooming on selected marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I populated my marker by a loop from an array it works fine. Next is I created a button dynamically inside the popup of the marker. now my problem is when I click the button supposed to be it will zoom on the current selected marker but its not. How can I fix that? here is my code

```
/* Show pop up on click */
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
    infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), this);

    /* Zoom In from current Marker */
    $('#zoomin').bind('click', function() {
        map.setCenter(marker.position);
        marker.setMap(map);
        map.setZoom(20);
    });

    /* Zoom Out from current Marker */
    $('#zoomout').bind('click', function() {          
        map.setCenter(phil);
        map.setZoom(7);
    });
});
```

Whole code (working but wrong zoom)

/* Whole Code for mapping */

```
    /* Initialize the map */
    function initMap() {
        /* Init. the map and center it in phil */
        var phil = {lat: 12.8797, lng: 121.7740};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: phil
        });

    /* 
    Create a marker on button click 
    google ref : event listener must be use
    */

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn-generate'), 'click', function(evt) {
        /* get the data of lat long for the markers */
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'qry_map.php', 
            success: function(data) {
                var arraypath = [];
                var markers = [];
                var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
                data1 = data1.aaData;

                for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {

                    /* Get lat and long */
                    var lat1 = data1[i].lat;
                    var lng1 = data1[i].long;
                    var lat2 = data1[i+1].lat;
                    var lng2 = data1[i+1].long;


                    /* Get FSP Details for marker pop up */
                    var code     =  data1[i].code;
                    var vdate    =  data1[i].vdate;
                    var timein   =  data1[i].nt1;
                    var timeout  =  data1[i].nt2;
                    var customer =  data1[i].name;
                    var address  =  data1[i].address;
                    var type     =  data1[i].type;

                    /* for checking see map lat and long */
                    console.log(lat1 + "," + lng1);

                    /* Put the markers */
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: {
                            lat: parseFloat(lat1),
                            lng: parseFloat(lng1)
                        },
                        map: map,
                        title: code
                    });

                    /* Pop up content */
                    marker.content = tableFSP(
                        code,
                        vdate,
                        timein,
                        timeout,
                        customer,
                        address,
                        type,
                        lat1,
                        lng1
                    );

                    /* Put the pop up in the markers */
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    /* Show pop up on click */
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
                        infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), this);

                        /* Zoom In from current Marker */
                        $('#zoomin').bind('click', function() {
                            marker.setMap(map);
                            map.setZoom(20);
                            map.setCenter(marker.position);
                        });

                        /* Zoom Out from current Marker */
                        $('#zoomout').bind('click', function() {          
                            map.setCenter(phil);
                            map.setZoom(7);
                        });
                    });

                    /* Create routing for each markers */
                    var link = 'decode.php?lat1=' + lat1 + '&lng1=' + lng1 + '&lat2=' + lat2 + '&lng2=' + lng2;
                    $.ajax({   
                        url: link, 
                        success: function(data) {
                            var data2 = data.points;
                            var arr_path = [];
                            for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
                                var lat = data2[j].lat;
                                var lng = data2[j].lng;
                                arr_path.push({'lat' : parseFloat(lat),'lng' : parseFloat(lng)});
                            }

                            var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                path: arr_path,
                                geodesic: true,
                                strokeColor:'red',
                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                strokeWeight: 2
                            });
                            Path.setMap(map);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: how do you calculate "phil" value ?

Comment: the phil is the lat long of phillipines. the error comes inside the `#zoomin`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#zoomin').bind('click', function() {
    marker.setMap(map);
    map.setZoom(20);
    map.setCenter(marker.position); // Moved after zoom
});
```

I don't remember if setZoom retains the previous center,so setting center after zoom is safer and more similar to the examples in google maps documentation.

Comment: It's the same as yours, only moved setcenter after zoom. Can you provide a working snippet ?

Comment: I cant provide a working snippet but I can provide a whole code for you please see the updated post

Comment: If you can't provide a working snippet, I assure that your code in the right context will work. Lacking context it is difficult to help more.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.